# Error in using WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,options,useSendInvoke)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Hi i am new to worklight. When i am trying to invoke the adapter using the client side call. There is a parameter in the invoke procedure api call.The parameter is useSendInvoke .What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question about useSendInvoke: [Use of third parameter in the WL.Client.InvokeProcedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246367/error-in-invoking-the-worklight-procedure)

To quote Anton:

> This parameter is used internally by WL authentication framework.
>   Technically there should not be a reason for developer to use it.
>
> There are several ways to invoke adapters.
>
> (1) First one is via client application. This is where you use
>   WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options) API.
>
> (2) Second is by using adapter invocation service -
>   http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_adapter_invocation_service.html.
>   Basically issuing an http request to WL server and getting a response
>   from adapter. RPC style.
>
> When you're doing it via (1) - you have two authentication layers -
>   first is security test defined for application, second is security
>   test defined for adapter procedure.
>
> When you're doing it via (2) - there is only one security layer -
>   security test defined for adapter procedure.
>
> UseSendInvoke param (which is, once again, for internal usage) means
>   that your application will go via path (2) instead of regular path
>   (1).