# Use of third parameter in the WL.Client.InvokeProcedure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using the client side API `WL.Client.InvokeProcedure(invocationData, options, UseSendInvoke)` in worklight 6. But I could not find a description for the parameter `UseSendInvoke` in the API. Do you guys know what it is?

Comment: "UseSendInvoke"? Where did you see this parameter in use?

Comment: I saw it when i am trying to use the client side api invokeProcedure in my eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parameter is used internally by WL authentication framework. Technically there should not be a reason for developer to use it.

There are several ways to invoke adapters.

(1) First one is via client application. This is where you use WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options) API.

(2) Second is by using adapter invocation service - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_adapter_invocation_service.html. Basically issuing an http request to WL server and getting a response from adapter. RPC style.

When you're doing it via (1) - you have two authentication layers - first is security test defined for application, second is security test defined for adapter procedure.

When you're doing it via (2) - there is only one security layer - security test defined for adapter procedure.

UseSendInvoke param (which is, once again, for internal usage) means that your application will go via path (2) instead of regular path (1).

Comment: But when i tried to type the api in my eclipse it automatically comes. Now i understood the meaning but i need to know how to use it

Comment: Do you have a link where i can read completely about the useSendInvoke

Comment: You will not find a documentation about this param. As I've said, this is internal one. It should not be documented, I will open a bug regarding this.

Comment: Hi @Anton sorry to post on this old thread, but as you said WL.Client.InvokeProcedure is an internal API and you will open a bug regarding this, I just wanted to ask if there is a way to restrict this API from being called?

Comment: The API is public, you can definitely use it. Third parameter is the internal one.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `UseSendInvoke` argument that `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` takes, at least not in the public API defined in the documentation. You can look at the documentation for [Worklight v6.0.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html), [Worklight v5.0.6](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html), [Worklight v5.0.5](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html) to learn more about that particular API.

Comment: No i found the parameter in worklight 6 only, but no description was given in the ibm information center. I searched for it but couldnt find it. So i posted here.

Comment: But where did you find it?

Comment: In the eclipse i tried to type the api and it automatically comes with that parameter. So i remove it and i invoke it.It is working fine but i just wanted to find the meaning and usuage of that parameter.